# 'assert' undeclared, despite assert.h being included in the file

Tags: c, include, assert

When I try and compile my code I get multiple errors concerning "assert", such as "unterminated list invoking macro assert" and "'assert' undeclared". This is despite me #include <assert.h> at the top of my code. Other files that use asserts which are in the same directory as this file compile and run with no errors, so I assume that it is the code which is the problem however I am unable to pinpoint what is causing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define NMBRS 1000000

int binIt (int k, int *a, int l, int r);
int binItRec (int k, int *a, int l, int r);
int interpSearch(int k, int * a, int l, int r);
int *parseArgs(int argc, char *argv[], int *n, int *search);

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i, n, search;
   int *a;
   int (*p[3])(int k, int *a, int l, int r) = {binIt, interpSearch};

   a = parseArgs(argc, argv, &n, &search);

   srand(time(NULL));

   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      a[i] = 2 * i;
   }
   for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
      if (search == 0) {
      assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
      }
   }
   free(a);

   return 0;
}

int binIt (int k, int *a, int l, int r)
{
   int m;

   while (l <= r) {
      m = (l + r) / 2; 
      if (k == a[m]) { 
         return m;
      } else {
         if (k > a[m]) { 
            l = m + 1;
         } else {
            r = m - 1;
         }
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

int binItRec (int k, int *a, int l, int r)
{
   int m;

   if (l > r) {
      return -1;
   }

   m = (l + r) / 2;

   if (k == a[m]) {
      return m;
   } else {
      if (k > a[m]) {
         return binItRec(k, a, m + 1, r);
      } else {
         return binItRec(k, a, l, m - 1);
      }
   }
}

int interpSearch(int k, int * a, int l, int r)
{
   int m;
   double md;

   while (l <= r) {
      md = ((double)(k - a[l]) / (double)(a[r] - a[l]) * (double)(r - l)) + (double)(l); 
      m = 0.5 + md; 
      if (k == a[m]) {
         return m;
      } else {
         if (k > a[m])
            l = m + 1;
         else {
            r = m - 1;
         }
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

int *parseArgs(int argc, char *argv[], int *n, int *search)
{
   int *p;

   if (argc != 3) {
      fprintf(stderr, "I was expecting 2 arguments: %s <n> <searchtype: 0/1/2\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   if (sscanf(argv[1], "%d", n) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "I was expecting 2 arguments: %s <n> <searchtype: 0/1/2\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   if (sscanf(argv[2], "%d", search) != 1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "I was expecting 2 arguments: %s <+ve n> <searchtype: 0/1/2\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   if ((*n < 1) || (*search < 0) || (*search > 2)) {
      fprintf(stderr, "I was expecting 2 arguments: %s <+ve n> <searchtype: 0/1/2\n", argv[0]);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }

   p = calloc(sizeof(int), *n);

   if (p == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failure to allocate memory\n");
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
   return p;
}
```

Here is the error:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -std=c90 -pedantic -lm -g3 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined    binarySearchUserv2.c   -o binarySearchUserv2
binarySearchUserv2.c: In function ‘main’:
binarySearchUserv2.c:126: error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "assert"
  126 | }
      |
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:7: error: ‘assert’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   29 |       assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
      |       ^~~~~~
binarySearchUserv2.c:5:1: note: ‘assert’ is defined in header ‘<assert.h>’; did you forget to ‘#include <assert.h>’?

    4 | #include <assert.h>
  +++ |+#include <assert.h>
    5 |
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:7: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
   29 |       assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
      |       ^~~~~~
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:13: error: expected ‘;’ at end of input
   29 |       assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
      |             ^
      |             ;
......
  126 | }
      |
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:7: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
   29 |       assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
      |       ^~~~~~
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:7: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
binarySearchUserv2.c:29:7: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
binarySearchUserv2.c:18:10: warning: unused variable ‘p’ [-Wunused-variable]
   18 |    int (*p[3])(int k, int *a, int l, int r) = {binIt, interpSearch};
      |          ^
binarySearchUserv2.c:126: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  126 | }
      |
make: *** [<builtin>: binarySearchUserv2] Error 1
```

Comment: You should add the entire error.

Comment: Often when you get a flood of errors like this it's best to ignore all but the first one or two. The first one tells you what's wrong -- "Unterminated argument list" is GCC-ese for "you have a missing close parenthesis somewhere (or, as in this case, too many open parentheses)".  The location of the first error is useless, but the location of the second error points you at the problem.

Comment: clang v10 does a better job of pointing directly at the problem: the first error is "test.c:28:7: error: unterminated function-like macro invocation", line 28 being the one with the bad `assert` call on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you're getting is at the end of the file at the last `}`.  This means you have an unbalanced parenthesis or braces somewhere.  The next error gives you a clue to where that's at:

```
assert((*p[search](a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
```

You're missing a `)`.  You want:

```
assert((*p[search])(a[rand() % n], a, 0, n - 1) >= 0);
```

Comment: And just like that the errors are gone, thank you! I should probably start looking more closely at the error messages

Comment: Additional: The second error is "'assert' undeclared" because the un-terminated argument list causes the preprocessor not to expand the macro `assert`. So `assert(...` passes on to the compiler proper, which sees it as  a call to an undeclared function (and then also complains about the unbalanced parentheses).

Comment: @Davospike When looking at error messages, always start at the top and fix them one at a time.